Why when I use it? <app-header></app-header> <router-outlet></router-outlet> then the path in the component header does not work
I have written an a tag as follows in the component header
user list
and then I use it in app.component as follows
When using this, the a tag doesn't work, I click on the a tag and nothing happens
But when I write the a tag directly in app.component.html like this, it works
Please help me explain why and tell me if there is any way to use it as the first image and still have the a tag work.

Please share your related routes too. How users/list is configured

I configured in the app.routes file as follows:
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {ListUserComponent} from './admin/component/userView/list-user/list-user.component'
export const routes: Routes = [
{
path:'user/list',
component:ListUserComponent
}
];

Are you import the routerLink directive in your app-header component (if you're using standalone components)? or import the routerModule in the module where you're declared the app-header component (if not)?

Hello, thank you for your support. I tried it and it worked
